# PhalconPHP view/layouts/controllers

Tags: view, phalcon, php, volt

I am new in Phalcon .I create a PhalconPHP application which is get menu elements from database. I use a layout to create the menu which is called in index.volt, but the layout call directly the model function.
I think this is not the best solution maybe i should use a controller between model and layout.

[image]

layout:

```
<?php

$menus = Menus::find();

foreach ($menus as $menu) {
    echo "<li>".$menu->name."</li>";
}
```

index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Phalcon PHP Framework</title>
    </head>

            <?php $this->partial("layouts/menus") ?>
        {{ content() }}

</html>
```

I would really appreciate, that somebody tell me what is the best solution for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of generating menu, you are looking probably for extending yout BaseController class. It's quite good practice for generating content you need on all your controllers like menu, meta-data or breadcrumbs.

```
class BaseController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller {
    function initialize() {

        $menus = Menus::find(array(
             // you may want to condition query based on user cookie
             // or controller you are in
            'conditions' => 'controller = "' . $this->dispatcher->getControllerName() . '"'
        ));

        // and set it as View variable to use it if you want
        $this->view->setVar('menus', $menus);
    }
}
```

And set all your controllers to use that as default:

```
class DefaultController extends BaseController { }
```

Than in menus.phtml:

```
<?php

    foreach ($menus as $menu) {
        echo "<li>".$menu->name."</li>";
    }
```

should be enough. Looks better in Volt:

```
<ul>
{% for menu in menus %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ menu.url }}">{{ menu.name }}</a>
    </li>
{% enfor %}
```

---

In case of more complex problems, like generating content only on 50% of your pages, you may want to put into View only parameters, eg.:

```
$this->view->setVar('menus', array(
    'conditions' => 'controller = "' . $this->dispatcher->getControllerName() . '"'
));
```

but that may be considered as not an elegant solution and is not preventing you from getting your hands on model in your View, what I assume you'd like to avoid. Slightly better would be setting an built query of [queryBuilder](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/phql.html#creating-queries-using-the-query-builder) and running its `->execute()` in view loop, to not stress DB as long as it's not necessary.